# GIT merge add files but does not keep its own files

Tags: git

I am doing a small test for starting to use merge in GIT. The reason for introducing merging is due to initiation of a co-operation with new developer on the team.

**My branches:**

- develop (has one file: "created_in_develop_branch.txt)
- feature/102-chat (has one file: chat_new.txt)
- master

**My used GIT commands:**

```
Step-1: [standing on feature/102-chat] merge develop

Step-2: Test and verify the merge.

Step-3: [standing on develop] merge feature/102-chat
```

My understanding is that (working in a team) it's good practice to first merge [develop => feature], test the merged result and only then merge [feature => develop].

When I do a: [standing on feature/102-chat] merge develop, the result is branch "feature/102-chat" is it removed the "chat_new.txt" and added "created_in_develop_branch.txt". Shouldn't both files exists after merging?

The behavior is the same when attempting to merge [standing on develop] merge feature/102-chat.

Here is the GIT response from merging [feature/102-chat => develop):

```
trader@test:/repos/git/experiments$ git merge feature/102-chat 
Updating f01887f..3fdef4d
Fast-forward
 chat_new.txt                  | 1 +
 created_in_develop_branch.txt | 1 -
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 chat_new.txt
 delete mode 100644 created_in_develop_branch.txt
```

**Question:** Why does GIT delete the file in develop branch when merging in feature/102-chat? Shouldn't the file in develop be kept and the result of the merging is to have both files from develop and feature/102-chat?

Comment: I can only assume that the file that exists in develop was removed in the feature branch - via a commit. In this case that action is replayed on develop when it's merged, hence the file is removed.

Comment: @fredrik. I see, I will delete the file content of both branches and perform another round of testing the mergin flow, paying attention to commit.

Comment: Git merges all changes, and that includes deletions and additions of files. If the file existed on develop when the branch was created, and was deleted on the branch, when you merge the branch into develop it will be gone there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is going on, it is generally a good thing to have a view of how commits are ordered among them.

All graphical front ends to git offer a history viewer,
you can also have a very good view in a terminal using `git log` and its vast list of options :

```
git log --oneline --graph

# you can view the combined history of any set of commits/branches :
git log --oneline --graph feature/102-chat develop master
```

---

In the history of your repo, you should see that branch `feature/102-chat` is actually already on top of `develop`. This is also indicated by the message :

```
...
Fast-forward
...
```

in the output of your `git merge` command.

This means that : from `git`'s view, the actions to move from `develop` to `feature/102-chat` include

- adding file `chat_new.txt`
- deleting file `created_in_develop_branch.txt`

This would not have been the case if `feature/102-chat` was forking from `develop` at an earlier point in `develop`'s history.